# how to send Broadcast to BroadcastReceiver when location of device changes, in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my android application, I want to `sendBroadcast` to `BroadcastReceiver` when the location of the device changes, even when my application is not running. I am new to android, please tell how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    LocationManager manager=    (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 manager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 10, 10, new LocationListener() {
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   sendBroadcast(rec); 
 }

 @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

 }
});
```

In order to broadcast in background you have to make use of AsyncTask or Service

Comment: I think this will work, but currently this is giving an error that is `Call requires permission which may be rejected by user`. please tell how to remove that error?

Comment: You have to add <uses-permission> in Manifest file.(include Access_FINE_Location and ACCESS_Coarse_LOCATION permission)